# Listener on AutoCompleteTextView (Android)

Tags: android, listener, autocompletetextview

I have an Activity with an `AutoCompleteTextView` and a `ListView` with an adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`.

When the Activity starts and `AutoCompleteTextView` is empty, `ListView` show a full list of items. When user starts typing on `AutoCompleteTextView` and selects a hint, an `OnItemClickListener` launch and I call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This reloads the adapter with only some items. This works perfect, but when the user cleans the `AutoCompleteTextView`, nothing happens.

I want to associate a `Listener` that launches when the user cleans, without pressing Enter.

Are there any `listener` that do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks wjeshak!!! Now works perfect.

This is the method that I've overrided, it can be useful for somebody :

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
    if ( start == 0 && before == 1 && count == 0) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could provide your own implementation of `TextWatcher` interface that checks whether user input has been cleared and add it to you `AutoCompleteTextBox` using `addTextChangedListener()` method